# Transform MongoDB collection by date

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with a schema that includes a date. I would like to shape the results of a query so that it is grouped by year and month, but not aggregated, just sorted.

So my model that looks like this:

```js
var RoundSchema = new Schema({
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: '{PATH} is required!'},
    course: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Course', required: '{PATH} is required!'},
    date: {type: Date, required: '{PATH} is required!'},
    score: Number
});
```

gets transformed like this:

```js
[
    {
        "year": 2014,
        "month": "April",
        "rounds": [
            {
                "user": "5334d6650685f68c22aa460b",
                "date": "2014-04-23T05:00:00.000Z",
                "course": "5340ab6000806e2433864cfc",
                "score": 73,
                "_id": "534f102667d635381834367b"
            },
            {
                "user": "5334d6650685f68c22aa460b",
                "date": "2014-04-21T05:00:00.000Z",
                "course": "5340ab6000806e2433864cfc",
                "score": 75,
                "_id": "534f100067d6353818343671"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "year": 2014,
        "month": "May",
        "rounds": [
            {
                "user": "5334d6650685f68c22aa460b",
                "date": "2014-05-05T05:00:00.000Z",
                "course": "5337611d8d03819024515cf9",
                "score": 81,
                "_id": "534dc38780f1a854236203f3"
            },
            {
                "user": "5334d6650685f68c22aa460b",
                "date": "2014-05-04T05:00:00.000Z",
                "course": "5337611d8d03819024515cf9",
                "score": 77,
                "_id": "534dc22c80f1a854236203e9"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am guessing that I can use map-reduce or the aggregation pipeline in MongoDB, but I can't get my head around the syntax. Feeling sharp as a bowling ball right now.

Anyone have an idea to get me kick-started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done quite simply using the aggregation framework. Which is not just for "summing" values, but also excels at document re-shaping.

Which is your best option as though the "non-aggregating" code can look a little simpler using mapReduce, as that process relies on a JavaScript interpreter, as opposed to the native code of the aggregation framework, and a mapReduce will therefore run much slower. Considerably so over large data.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Place all items in an array by year and month
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "year": { "$year": "$date" },
            "month": { "$month": "$date" },
        },
        "rounds": { "$push": {
           "user": "$user",
           "date": "$date",
           "course": "$course",
           "score": "$score",
           "_id": "$_id"
        }}
    }},

    // Sort the results by year and month
    { "$sort": { "_id.year": 1, "_id.date": 1 } }, 

    // Optional project to your exact form
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "year": "$_id.year",
        "month": "$_id.month",
        "rounds": 1
    }}

])
```

Or possibly without the arrays you specify and leave everything just in a flat form:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "year": { "$year": "$date" },
        "month": { "$month": "$date" },
        "user": 1,
        "date": 1,
        "course": 1,
        "score": 1
    }},
    { "$sort": { "year": 1, "month": 1 } }
])
```

Or even do it to exactly how you specify with the month names:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Place all items in an array by year and month
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "year": { "$year": "$date" },
            "month": { "$month": "$date" },
        },
        "rounds": { "$push": {
           "user": "$user",
           "date": "$date",
           "course": "$course",
           "score": "$score",
           "_id": "$_id"
        }}
    }},

    // Sort the results by year and month
    { "$sort": { "_id.year": 1, "_id.date": 1 } }, 

    // Optionally project to your exact form
    { "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "year": "$_id.year",
      "month": { "$cond": [
        { "$eq": [ "$_id.month": 1 ] },                 
        "January",
        { "$cond": [
          { "$eq": [ "$_id.month": 2 ] },
          "February",
          { "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$_id.month": 3 ] },
            "March",
            { "$cond": [
              { "$eq": [ "$_id.month": 4 ] },
              "April",
              { "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ "$_id.month": 5 ] },
                "May",
                { "$cond": [
                  { "$eq": [ "$_id.month": 6 ] },
                  "June",
                  { "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$_id.month": 7 ] },
                    "July",
                    { "$cond": [
                      { "$eq": [ "$_id.month": 8 ] },
                      "August",
                      { "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": [ "$_id.month": 9 ] },
                        "September",
                        { "$cond": [
                          { "$eq": [ "$_id.month": 10 ] },
                          "October",
                          { "$cond": [
                            { "$eq": [ "$_id.month": 11 ] },
                            "November",
                            "December"
                          ]}
                        ]}
                      ]} 
                    ]}
                  ]} 
                ]}
              ]}
            ]}
          ]}                 
        ]}
      ]},
      "rounds": 1
    }}

])
```

Which is overkill of course, but just to show that it can be done.

And there is of course the [Operator reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) so you can understand the usages of the operators used. And you may well want to alter this by adding your own **`$match`** condition to restrict the date range that you are looking at. Or indeed for other purposes.

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you. I dropped that first example into a controller and it works perfectly. I think I'll do the ugly month transformation in the UI.

Comment: As a Mongo newb, this was the best I could come up with: `db.rounds.find().sort({date: 1}).map(function(r) { r.year = r.date.getFullYear(); r.month = r.date.getMonth(); return r })`